# Editing a rigged mesh (MakeHuman > Blender > Unity)

Tags: animation, rigging, bones, unity, makehuman

I'm trying to use this program called MakeHuman which creates a rigged mesh for you, but I am trying to edit the mesh in Blender before using it in Unity. There are so many layers and complexity to the Blender scene that I don't know what to do, even given that I have done basic rigging manually before.

For simplicity in example, I would like to replace the head of the mesh with a cube. I believe what I must do is:

1. Unparent the mesh from the rig (how do I do this properly?)
2. Edit the mesh
3. Re-parent the mesh to the rig
4. Assign automatic weight painting

I've tried this before and what I get is my character floating in space in Unity, I believe because there is something wrong with the weight painting?

Please help!

Thanks

http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37244

[image]

Recently I've tried clearing all the Vertex Groups and modifier after Clear Parent, editing my mesh, then reparenting with automatic weight. When I go to bring this into Unity with animations put onto it, it just stands there.
[image]

Comment: Your file isn't showing up on paste bin.  Please add it directly to your question ([How to add a blend file](https://blend-exchange.com/help))  Also, MakeHuman has several options for what kind of rig to export, and there are two different ways of importing a MakeHuman character into blender.  Can you add those steps to your explanation?

Answer (score 0):

I think your steps should look more like the following:

1. Edit the mesh

   1.1 - delete the vertices for the head

   1.2 - shift+a (to add) and select cube (while still in edit mode)

   1.3 - The cube should be selected. Place the cube (g button) to desired location.

   1.4 - make sure the vertices of the cube are still selected, and go into the "data" panel (icon is a polygon triangle thingy), find the vertex group named "DEF-head", and assign the cube vertices to that group (set slider to 1.0 and click "Assign" button).

Comment: Hi @beiller,

Thanks for the reply. I have tried this where I have:


1 - Imported the new "head" I want

2 - Selected the original mesh and deleted the weighted head vertices

3 - Joining the two meshes together

4 - Assigning the new vertices (all selected) to be weighted under the DEF-head vertices group

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/KsjrGyQ.png

Comment: Wow that looks super creepy! :) Make sure the armature is not a parent to the mesh (alt+p). We only want to use the "Armature" modifier, not parenting. Also when joining, try both orderings. I think the makehuman mesh should be the second one selected, but also try vice versa.